# synchronize css animation with page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know there is a bunch of questions like this but none really answering my question.
I had make a preloader with css animation and I want to be synchronised with page load. I can trigger the animation on page load but I want to manage the time that animation last somehow so to follow exactly the page load (even if it's too fast).

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/RgPU7/

I want the 'filling' effect to follow page load time.

Right now I just apply a delay and a fadeout effect to the modal that wraps the css animation.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  $(".modal").delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can always delay a function like this

```
setTimeout(function() { your_func(); }, 5000);
```

or you can do something like this

```
$(this).fadeOut(500, function(){
   //Do something 
   $(this).fadeIn(700);
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't the best way to achieve this I think because I will always have a 5" delay, even if page load time is 2" for example